# Why can't a class val parameter be call-by-name?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a class to aggregate as a single interface a bunch of proxies for API functions. A couple of these are nullary functions, but I don't want the act of including them in the class constructor to trigger the API calls. My solution right now is to wrap the call in a literal nullary function `new myClass(() => apiCall)` and then calling the member function explicitly. This isn't all that bad, but I'm wondering if there's a technical reason I can't just use a call-by-name parameter to pass lazy reference to the method?

Example:

```
scala> class MyClass(val apiCall: => String)
<console>:1: error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
       class MyClass(val apiCall: => String)
```

**Edit** I should have specified that my question is why a class can't have a `val` parameter. Added an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class can very well have call-by-name parameters, as long as they are not `val` or `var`:

```
> scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo(f: => Unit) {
     |   def run(): Unit = f
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(println("hello"))
res0: Foo = Foo@5da6b8c6

scala> res0.run()
hello
```

The reason a `val` or `var` parameter cannot be by-name is simply that a class field cannot be by-name, no more than local variable, for that matter. So the following is invalid:

```
scala> class FooInvalid(val v: => Unit) {
<console>:1: error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
       class FooInvalid(val v: => Unit) {
                               ^
```

However, it is possible to have a by-name parameter that is assigned, *as a function* to a `val` field, like this (but then you have to use `()` as call site):

```
scala> class FooVal(v0: => Unit) {
     |   val v: () => Unit = () => v0
     | }
defined class FooVal

scala> new FooVal(println("hello"))
res2: FooVal = FooVal@75c145bc

scala> res2.v
res3: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> res2.v()
hello
```

Finally, instead of defining `v` as a `val` of type `() => Unit`, you can define it as `def` of type `Unit`. And then you get the behavior you probably wanted in the first place:

```
scala> class FooDef(v0: => Unit) {
     |   def v: Unit = v0
     | }
defined class FooDef

scala> new FooDef(println("hello"))
res5: FooDef = FooDef@2e04a041

scala> res5.v
hello
```

One could argue that the compiler should do this transformation itself, but that would not be consistent with the semantics that a `val` must be *stable* (e.g., with a stable value you can `import x._` its members, which you cannot do with an unstable value) since a `def` (even without `()`) is a not a stable value. Best to leave this small rewriting to the user rather than introduce a very weird unsoundness.

Comment: But not if they're `val`s, and that's my question. Sorry, should have been more specific.

Comment: Great answer. Regarding your comparison to local variables, a local variable cannot be by-name, but it can be lazy. The compiler whines about this too though, recommending using by-name parameters, no less.

Comment: That would be because lazy *parameters* do not exist in general. They were considered for inclusion in Scala at some point, but it turned out that they were more difficult to implement than reasonable, so that was dropped.